# rerender does not work when the outputPanel id is made unique

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, actionfunction, outputpanel

```
<apex:page id="idPageComponent" standardController='Case' extension='testController'>
<apex:form id="idForm">
    <apex:actionFunction name="testMethod" action="{!testMethodDetails}" reRender="{!$Component.idPageComponent.idForm.outerOutput}{!intNumber}"
                         onComplete="executeAfterComplete('{!$Component.idPageComponent.idForm.outerOutput}{!intNumber}')">
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:repeat value="{!testRule.testInfo}" var="objSections" id="testInfo">
        <apex:outputPanel id="outerOutput">
            <h3>{!objSections.Title}</h3>
            <div class="container-fluid" data-columnNumber="{!objSections.Columns}">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!mapValues[objSections.Id]}" var="sectionFields">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
                            <apex:variable var="c" value="{!sectionFields.apiName}"/>
                            <label>{!sectionFields.Labels}
                                <apex:inputField value="{!case[c]}"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
</apex>
```

The above is in a VF page named test.page. There is a javascript which updates the `id` attribute in the page, and adds incremental number to it. So say, for the first time when a create button is clicked an action fucntion gets called and the id of `span` changes from `idPageCreateCase:j_id86:idPageComponent:idForm:outerOutput` to `idPageCreateCase:j_id86:idPageComponent:idForm:outerOutput0`. This is just to make sure each outPut panel has a unique id.

So I am also placing the reRender id as  `{!$Component.idPageComponent.idForm.outerOutput}{!intNumber}` so that it finds the proper outputPanel to update. 
I have even passed `{!$Component.idPageComponent.idForm.outerOutput}{!intNumber}` from onComplete just to make sure that the id generated is `idPageCreateCase:j_id86:idPageComponent:idForm:outerOutput0`

But Still the output panel does not rerender. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: you might be running into this `You cannot use the reRender attribute to update content in a table.` from [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax_partial_page_updates.htm). I realize this is not a table but repeat shares characteristics. What I've done in the past is to use a wrapper class for each repeat element in the controller and a Boolean isVisible getter as a property of that wrapper class. Then, after action  executes, page refreshes and invisible output panels vaporize

Comment: I dont want to hide the panels and neither there is any error message, All the panels should be there on UI but only refresh should happen on the particular panel for which the reRender attribute matches. Is there any way?

Comment: i remember struggling with this years ago and I ended up rerendering the whole table - but I found [this that might help you](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111274/only-rerender-row-in-apexpageblocktable-using-apexactionregion/112165)